# Toopltip inside IconButton not visible on tap

Tags: react-native, expo, tooltip, native-base, iconbutton

I have an iconButton box and inside it, I have a Tooltip icon like below:

```
            <IconButton
                Icon={() => 
                    <View> 
                      {p.s === "app" && (<Tooltip label="App" bg="#FFF" _text={{color:"#000"}}>
                      <AntDesign name="checkcircle" size={24} color="#58C064" /></Tooltip>
                    <View>
                      <Image source={icons.pict}/>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                }
               
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate(...})}
              />
```

I long tap on the check circle icon on mobile but do not see the tooltip, it instead interprets it as a press and executes on Press.

I tried separating icons from images like

```
<View>
 {p.s === "app" && (<Tooltip label="App" bg="#FFF" _text={{color:"#000"}}>
                          <AntDesign name="checkcircle" size={24} color="#58C064" /></Tooltip>
<IconButton
                    Icon={() => 
                        <View> 
                        <View>
                          <Image source={icons.pict}/>
                        </View>
                      </View>
                    }
                   
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate(...})}
                  />

</View>
```

but it still does not show up in the tooltip although the button press is now focused on just the image.

How would the tooltip show up?

Comment: I guess that `p.s` is a state? However, I do not see that you change the state on press?

Comment: This value is coming from the backend fetch query. It is already set or unset and based on that I either render the icon with tooltip or not.